# SQL Order BY Varchar as DateTime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, sql-order-by

I have a varchar row in my DB which looks like dd/mm/yyyy.
I'm trying to order it, but for now it order by day -> month -> year instead of year -> month -> day.

I've tried using

```
SELECT * FROM Evenement
ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, DateEvenement,103)";
```

so it should order correctly.

Sadly, I get an error when using it

```
Erreur sur la requete : <font color="red">SELECT * FROM Evenement ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, DateEvenement,103)|Erreur de syntaxe près de 'DateEvenement,103)' à la ligne 1</font>
```

And I can't seem to figure what's wrong.

Code :

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Evenement ORDER BY CONVERT(DateTime, DateEvenement,103)";
$AllEvents = parcoursRs(SQLSelect($SQL));
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($AllEvents);
```

parcoursRS :

```
function parcoursRs($result) {
    if($result == false) return array();

    while ($ligne = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        $tab[]= $ligne;

    return $tab;
}
```

Where I'm trying to use my json :

```
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    listEvent = "";
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        listEvent += "<div class='evenement'>";
        listEvent += "<input type='button' class='delete' value='Supprimer' title='" + data[i].idEvenement + "'/>";
        listEvent += "<label>Évènement: " + data[i].Titre + "</label></br><label>Heure de début: " + data[i].HeureDebut + "</label></br><label> Heure de fin: " + data[i].HeureFin + "</label></br><label> Description : " + data[i].Presentation + "</label></br><label> Date : " + data[i].DateEvenement + "</label></br>";
        listEvent += "</div>";
    }
```

It works perfectly (with the wrong order ofc ...) if I use

```
$SQL = "SELECT * FROM Evenement ORDER BY DateEvenement";
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why you do not store the dates in a column with a date datatype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the T-SQL syntax (Microsoft SQL Server), whereas your tag suggest you are actually using MySQL Server. In MySQL you need to use STR_TO_DATE instead, for example:

```
SELECT * FROM Evenement ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(DateEvenement, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `str_to_date` function as below for `mysql`

```
order by str_to_date(col_name,'%d/%m/%Y');
```